# Cloudwatch metrics - Math expression SUM([IF]) on AWS is not giving valid result

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have created metrics m1 based on sample count. I am trying to filter the datapoints which are above the threshold value of 13000. I am using the If expression to do the evaluation.

```
IF(m1 > 13000, m1, 0)
```

The IF expression is showing the right graph. Now I want to count or sum the number of datapoints provided by the IF statement. And the SUM does not work correctly it does not give the filtered count instead it gives the total count of m1. I have found some other posts where they did mention that SUM does not work for the expression. The SUM expression added with IF filter within it is as follows:

```
SUM([IF(m1 > 13600, m1, 0)])
```

I did try different other expressions as well to get the count of the above metric like METRIC_COUNT, DATAPOINT_COUNT and few others but it does not provide correct value. I want to view this value on the Number graph but the SUM metric expression does not provide right output.